# Regex pattern not printing matches from text

Tags: python, regex

I tested my code to make sure my pattern matches a test case `test` but for some reason it's not finding matches in a string of text `text_to_search`. Can anyone help me out here? At first I thought I fixed it because I forgot about using the `.group(0)` to print the full match but it's still not working.

Here is my code:

```
test = 'E000.1'
text_to_search = '''

237.0-237.2 is the range for the ICD-9 codes for neoplasm of uncertain behavior of\
endocrine glands and nervous system. On the hand, the ICD-9 code for Type II Diabetes\
with other manifestations is 250.8x where x is 0 or 2 depending on controlled or\
uncontrolled.

'''
pattern = re.compile(r'^(V\d{2}(\.\w{1,3})?|\d{3}(\.\w{1,2})?|E\d{3}(\.\w{1,2})?)-?(V\d{2}(\.\w{1,3})?|\d{3}(\.\w{1,2})?|E\d{3}(\.\w{1,2})?)?$')

matches = pattern.finditer(text_to_search)

for match in matches:
    print(matches.group(0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have anchors in your regular expression `^...$` which assert that the match needs to be the entirety of the string (from its beginning to its end). The entirety of the string is obviously not a match candidate (and you know it, or you wouldn't be trying to find multiple matches with `finditer`).

Remove those anchors.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(V\d{2}(\.\w{1,3})?|\d{3}(\.\w{1,2})?|E\d{3}(\.\w{1,2})?)-?(V\d{2}(\.\w{1,3})?|\d{3}(\.\w{1,2})?|E\d{3}(\.\w{1,2})?)?')
```

Comment: that makes so much sense thank you! I totally missed that. I edited a previous ICD-9 regex pattern and didn't even notice that. I am new to using regular expressions so this was a good lesson learned.